# Set separate process window owner

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a form within my application that needs to be set as the owner of a form from a completely separate process (for example, Notepad). I tried creating a NativeWindow instance but it doesn't have an owner property. Any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm going for?